# KeyListener not working?

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to make the Snake game. But i am not able to move a rectangular box(which is the Snake).
Sorry for asking such a question! But i am a beginer in java and i have no idea where the problem in my code is.

```
    class Snakexx extends JPanel implements ActionListener , KeyListener{
public static int a,b,x,y;
public int fooda,foodb;
Random rnd ;
Timer t = new Timer(1,this);
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
         if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_UP)
        {
        x=0;
        y=-1;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_LEFT)
        {
        x=-1;
        y=0;            
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_DOWN)
        {
        x=0;
        y=1;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_RIGHT)
         {
            x=1;
            y=0;
            }
        }
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent f){}

protected Snakexx(){
rnd = new Random();
fooda=rnd.nextInt(1300);
foodb=rnd.nextInt(300);
a=20;
b=20;
t.start();
addKeyListener(this);
setFocusable(true);

} 



protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

super.paintComponent(g);
g.fillRect(a,b,10,10) ;
g.fillRect(fooda,foodb,10,10) ;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
a+=x;
b+=y;
Graphics gr;
gr= new Snakexx().getGraphics();
gr.fillRect(a,b,10,10) ;

}
}

 public class Snake2{


 public static void main(String args[]) 
{
Snakexx abcd = new Snakexx();
JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Snake Game");
jfrm.setSize(1300, 650);
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jfrm.setVisible(true);

jfrm.add(abcd);
}


}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is `NullPointerException` in the timer action. `new Snakexx().getGraphics();` is an incorrect way to get `Graphics` instance. It is even more problematic as you're actually allocating new instance of a panel on every tick of a timer.

Don't use `getGraphics()` for your painting, as it is temporary buffer which is recycled on next repaint. Do you painting in `paintComponent()` and call `repaint()` if needed.

Immediate fix would be adding `repaint()` and commenting out the painting code, ie:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    a += x;
    b += y;
    // Graphics gr;
    // gr= new Snakexx().getGraphics();
    // gr.fillRect(a,b,10,10) ;

    repaint();
}
```

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information.

Also, key listeners are a low-level interface to keyboard input. Make sure the panel is focusable and has focus. Focusing can be very tricky. It is much better to use Key Bindings, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.